# Navigation utility without browser, light weight and fail-proof

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I have a use case where I need to fill the form in a website but don't have access to API. Currently we are using webdriver along with browser but it gets very heavy and not fool proof as the process is asynchronous. Is there any way I can do it without browser and also make the process synchronous by closely monitoring the pending requests?

Casperjs and htmlunitdriver seems to be some of the best options I have. Can someone explain advantages or disadvantages in terms of maintenance, fail-proof, light weight.

I would need to navigate complex and many different types of webpages. Some of the webpages I would like to navigate are heavily JS driven.

**Can Scrapy be used for this purpose?**

Comment: Maybe [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) could help, possibly with [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have been working with a LOT of different ways of doing this, dependable on how intelligent/advanced you want the system to be. I'm on ruby, and in ruby it's quite easy to do. Beneath are the methods I found most useful listed (of cause pretty ruby biased):

- **Mechanize** ([found here](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org)): Super light weight, super fast, and super reliable. It handles everything a browser does, except for JS. Under the hood it's a open-uri + an XML parser with nice interface layer on top and a little extra spice. Checkout the tutorials in the documentation. I think it's also available for something like python and others.
- **Poltergeist** ([found here](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist)): Fast, real browser like behavior, pretty reliable and light weight, supports JS. Under the hood it's a phantom-js driven browser for capybara (but without all the nasty dependencies, and completely headless). Even though it's build for testing with e.g. rspec, it's easy to use in other ways, or as stand alone, just search google.
- **Watir-webdriver** ([found here](http://watirwebdriver.com)): A super powerful library for driving REAL browsers like firefox, IE, chrome or safari. It's actually pretty stable. However if you don't have a real physical screen attached (e.g. on a server), you need to run xvfb, and map the output of the browser to it. This can be done very easily with the headless gem also mentioned [here](http://watirwebdriver.com/headless/)

So in other words, if your don't need JS support, go with mechanize.

Comment: I would like to navigate many types of webpages and I am expecting to need javascript. If javascript is not supported won't we be not able to do many actions? Selecting dropdowns or clicking on buttons would all require javascript isn't it?

Comment: No not at ALL! This is very important to understand! Regular html forms, links buttons etc. is NOT JS driven. You can find out if the action you wan't to perform is JS driven or not, by deactivating JS in  your browser, and then test out what you wan't to do, in the browser.

Comment: I am currently working in python and very much familiar with java. I checked with javascript turned off for my browser. Some of the webpages I need to navigate are heavily js driven.

Comment: OK, well it's always more stable to go without JS, because it's so much more simple. I would go with http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/ then. The pages that "needs" JS might actually not need it. E.g. say you wan't to click a link that is made with a JS method. Then instead of actually executing that JS, then parse the JS code, see what url that it WOULD send you to, and then go to it manually using mechanize. A good tool for understanding what's happening on the page is good old firebug in combination with a plugin called Tamper Data - check it out, and get familiar with working that way

Comment: Is there any phantomjs driven but syntax is in python or java. Casperjs seemed to work well for my purpose but code has to be written in javascript. any difference ort advantages of either of Poltergeist or casperjs. I wouldn't want to use Mechanise as it becomes difficult for me to deal with ajax or js heavy websites.

Comment: Okay, well Poltergeist is a pure ruby based interface. But under the hood it's executing phantom-js. casperjs is another dsl in js like poltergeist is for ruby. Now in python there are many libraries for things like this. E.g. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ (a bit like mechanize), http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/ (based on the webkit js driver). Search the web for python based web page testing and scraping tools that supports js.

Comment: Can scrapy be used for this purpose?

Comment: I don't think scrapy has js support. But is similar to mechanize

Answer (score 5):

Use **Htmlunitdriver**.For making it fail proof You would have to make some changes accordingly.But It will work without browser.