# Can scrapy be used to complete form submission and do everything what a browser can do

Tags: python, scrapy, phantomjs, casperjs

I have a task where in I need to submit a form to website but they dont provide any API. I am currently using webdriver and faced many problems because of asynchronous nature between my code and browser. I am looking for a light weight reliable library/tool using with I can do all the tasks a user do with a browser.

Casperjs is one of the option which can do my job but I am more familiar with python and scrapy has larger developer community compare to casperjs.

[Navigation utility without browser, light weight and fail-proof](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873719/navigation-utility-with-out-browser-light-weight-and-fail-proof) is one of the related question.

Comment: Sure, you can submit forms: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-usage-examples

Comment: does it have any limitations when compared to web browser in terms of functionalities. The form I want is very complex and has all kinds of web items any form can have.

Comment: Scrapy can't run javascript, so if some form value is calculated by javascript, it'll be complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in short answer is **No**.
scrapy can't render java script but browser can.

you can use Selenium.

if you are sure to use scrapy and there is javascript that you need to run you can use

[scrapy with selenium](http://snipplr.com/view/66998/rendered-javascript-crawler-with-scrapy-and-selenium-rc/)

[scrapy with gtk/webkit/jswebkit](http://snipplr.com/view/66996/renderedinteractive-javascript-with-gtkwebkitjswebkit/)

[scrapy with webdrivers](http://snipplr.com/view/66997/rendered-javascript-with-webdrivers/)

Answer (score 1):

If you like CasperJS but want to stick with Python, you should have a look at [Ghost.py](https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py)